# Python Kivy: How to optimize screen resolution for all devices?

Tags: android, optimization, kivy, screen, resolution

Im just started to coding with kivy and working on it.But im wondering, how can i optimize screen resolution for apk apps. I mean ,im using `Window.size = (423,750)` and controlling after coding with this resolution. So trying to create all widgets with boxlayouts, size_hints. But when im checking my application on Genymotion or Android devices, my widgets dont look like i created on linux.

For an example ,I use that for texts: `font_size: '18sp'`.But it doesn't looks like as i wanted.It's size changes when i check on different genymotion android devices and sometimes boxlayout blocks its size and makes it unreadable.

Is there a any command for auto screen resolution on each devices or should i create these font_size just like that : `font_size: str(root.width*.05)+'sp'` (So should i change my all codes like these `spacing: 30` to `spacing: root.height*.007` ) ? Any help would be good for beginners like me.How should i optimize all widgets and texts ? Thanks for reading and answering..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, **DON'T** use `Window.size` to control the size of the window since you don't know what size your device will be in the end. Second, in kv, you can define your font size with the `sp()` or `dp()` helper functions, for example:

```py
Label:
  text: 'Hello'
  font_size: sp(18)
```

To preview your app while developing, you can test with different devices by:

1. Checking the respective device's resolution
2. Checking the device's dpi

So, for example to *emulate* a Samsung S9+, which has a resolution of `1440x2960` and a dpi of `529`. you would run your app like this:

`python main.py --size=1440x2960 --dpi=529`

This will give you the results you want, if using this method, i find it much easier to work with the `dp()` helper function instead of the `sp()` as what you have now is the dpi so kivy can use that.

Just a quick note, if your screen is smaller than the specified size, e.g on my laptop with a resolution of `1366x768`, you simply need to scale the size down, e.g run it as:

`python main.py --size=360x740 --dpi=529`

Its the same resolution but scaled to about a quarter of the original size to make it fit on your screen.

FYI, you can also use the `dp()` and `sp()` functions in your `.py` file, simply import them like this:

`from kivy.metrics import dp, sp`

Comment: That's fine for testing, but for a final release, isn't there a way to grab the resolution of the device kivy's running on and scale the app (and its contents) to fit?

Comment: BTW, thanks for the tip on how to import sp() and dp(). I've been looking all over for that tidbit.

Comment: @no-one Well you really wouldn't want that actually. Kivy has `size_hint`s on all widgets to cater for different screen sizes, `size_hint` auto scales but if you insist on doing it manually, you can get the runtime screen size from the `Window`: `from kivy.core.window import Window`, then: `Window.height # screen height`, `Window.width # screen width`, `Window.size # [screen_width, screen_height]`. Then you could do something like `my_btn.width == Window.width * .2 # 20% of the window's width` which is literally what `my_btn.size_hint_x: .2` will do anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
from kivy.utils import platform
```

Here's one approach... It sets the app to full screen when testing/running on Android or iOS, but uses a reasonable size (602, 1024) for testing on the desktop:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        if(platform == 'android' | platform == 'ios'):
            Window.maximize()
        else:
            Window.size = (620, 1024)

        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```